# Implement javascript sorting in a asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net, javascript, view, grid

How can I accomplish gridview sorting in client browser using javascript ? without using inbuilt gridview sorting method. I really dont want the gridview to go to the DB each time while sorting.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

....

<script type="text/javascript">
    var aspxElements = {
        theGrid: '<%= myGrid.ClientID %>' //I'm not entierly sure this is the id of the table or some container element
    };

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#' + aspxElements.theGrid).tablesorter(); 
    });
</script>
```

(modified from the demo on this [page](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo))

Note that this will get weird if you're using pagination.